# Signal toggled on gtkcellrenderer of treeview column only occurs the first time i click. PYGTK + GLADE

Tags: python, gtk3, pygtk

Signal toggled on gtkcellrenderer of treeview column only occurs the first time i click. Why?

```
def on_cr2_toggled(self, widget, path):
    store = builder.get_object("treestore1")
    booleano = store[path][1]
    store[path][1] = not booleano
    booleano = not booleano
    print("now")
```

When i press toggle cell the first time, the event/signal occurs (and the toggle square change), but the second time y press the signal don't occurs. Only prints "now" in the first click, the second not, then the event don't process.  why? i do not understand.
I use Glade for de UI, y defined my signal "on_cr2_toggled" on GtkCellRenderedToggle -> toggled.

thank you!

Comment: why is your code commented out?

Comment: Sorry, it is the first time i comment on stackoverflow and i do not know how i put my code. but in my program the code is not commented.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem was in Glade. I switch the "Activable" and "conmutable state". I put on the first and indicate treestore field in second. Now it works!.